# swift3 Alamofire xml data

Tags: swift, alamofire

> here is data

```
Data: <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<string xmlns="http://192.168.80.41:8081/WebServiceTest.asmx">[
  {
    "NonCID": "n10909",
    "Name": "aaaa",
    "ClassType": "aa",
    "City": "aaa",
    "Area": "aaa",
    "Address": "aaaa",
    "TelArea": "02",
    "Tel": "29857456",
    "Latitude": 25.062047000000000,
    "Longitude": 121.495241000000000
  },
  {
    "NonCID": "n10957",
    "Name": "xxxx",
    "ClassType": "xx",
    "City": "xxx",
    "Area": "xxx",
    "Address": "xxxxx",
    "TelArea": "02",
    "Tel": "29736693",
    "Latitude": 25.061227100000000,
    "Longitude": 121.495149900000000
  },
  {
    "NonCID": "n10958",
    "Name": "xxxx",
    "ClassType": "xx",
    "City": "xxx",
    "Area": "xxx",
    "Address": "xxxx",
    "TelArea": "02",
    "Tel": "29821024",
    "Latitude": 25.061812900000000,
    "Longitude": 121.495274000000000
  }]</string>
```

> Here is my code

```
Alamofire.request("http://localhost/WebServiceTest.asmx/") .responseData { response in
            debugPrint("All Response Info: \(response)")
              if let data = response.result.value, let utf8Text = String(data: data, encoding: .utf8) {
                print("Data: \(utf8Text)")

            }
        }
```

when I run this code get the data like i post, and i can't get the data form [{"noncid":"xxxx","Name":"bbb", ........etc  }]  to dictionary.

Does anyone know how can i get the data to dictionary that I can use.
or have another way can do that. thanks all cheers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`NSXMLParser`](https://developer.apple.com/reference/foundation/xmlparser) to parse the text associated with the `string` XML element name. Then, once you have that text, which appears to be JSON, use [`NSJSONSerialization`](https://developer.apple.com/reference/foundation/jsonserialization) to parse the contents out of the JSON string.

```
func parse(data: Data) {
    // parse the xml

    let parser = XMLParser(data: data)
    parser.delegate = self
    guard parser.parse() else {
        print("xml parse error: \(parser.parserError?.localizedDescription)")
        return
    }

    // get the parsedXMLString from

    guard let value = parsedXMLString, let jsonData = value.data(using: .utf8) else {
        print("cannot convert to data")
        print("string: \(parsedElementValue)")
        return
    }

    // try now parsing the JSON body 

    do {
        guard let responseObject = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: jsonData) as? [[String: Any]] else {
            print("Unable to parse array of dictionaries from JSON")
            print(value)
            return
        }

        // use responseObject here

        print(responseObject)
    } catch let jsonError {
        print("Unable to parse json: \(jsonError)")
    }
}
```

Where you have a few properties:

```
fileprivate var parsedXMLString: String?
fileprivate var parsedElementValue: String?
```

And you implement an extension for the XML Parser:

```
extension ViewController: XMLParserDelegate {

    func parser(_ parser: XMLParser, didStartElement elementName: String, namespaceURI: String?, qualifiedName qName: String?, attributes attributeDict: [String : String] = [:]) {
        if elementName == "string" {
            parsedElementValue = ""
        }
    }
    func parser(_ parser: XMLParser, foundCharacters string: String) {
        parsedElementValue?.append(string)
    }

    func parser(_ parser: XMLParser, didEndElement elementName: String, namespaceURI: String?, qualifiedName qName: String?) {
        if elementName == "string" {
            parsedXMLString = parsedElementValue
            parsedElementValue = nil
        }
    }
}
```

I must be said, though, that this is a very strange format, to see JSON inside XML. Usually you have one or the other...